# Displaying a negative time in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I am developing a timer in Delphi 2009. I am currently using the following to format my timer display:

```
Caption := Format('%.2d', [Hours]) + ':' + 
           Format('%.2d', [Minutes]) + ':' + 
           Format('%.2d', [Seconds]);
```

and this as expected displays the time as:

```
00:04:35
```

However, when I go into negative time it is understandably displaying it as:

```
00:-04:-35
```

I need the time to display as:

```
-00:04:35
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Prefix:='';
    if (Hours<0) or (Minutes<0) or (Seconds<0) then
    Prefix:='-';

```
Caption := Prefix+Format('%.2d', [Abs(Hours)]) + ':' + 
           Format('%.2d', [Abs(Minutes)]) + ':' + 
           Format('%.2d', [Abs(Seconds)]);
```

Bye.

Comment: Thanks can't believe how simple this was...think I have been staring at it too long...

Comment: Why don't you call `Format('%.2d:%.2d:%.2d', [...])` with all three values in one go?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're formatting each number separately, therefore its no surprise you get negative sign on all of them. Try this:

```
Caption := Format('%.2d', [Abs(Hours)]) + ':' + 
           Format('%.2d', [Abs(Minutes)]) + ':' + 
           Format('%.2d', [Abs(Seconds)]);

if (Hours < 0) or (Minutes < 0) or (Seconds < 0) then begin
  Caption := '-' + Caption;
end;
```

Comment: Nice, voted up as helpful even though it doesn't even compile.